# Extraing individual field values from an InfluxDB database

Tags: select, store, influxdb, node-red

My apologies if this is a trivial question. I am capturing data from a BMP280 temperature/pressure sensor and publishing it via MQTT. Using Node Red, I am formatting the data into payloads like `"BMP2801 temp=23.57,pres=1013.8"` and storing it in an influxdb on Raspberry Pi. The queries shown in the image below seem to indicate that I am storing successfully - though possibly not in the right format for retrieval.

[image: Database content - as stored]

My question is how to frame a select statement to retrieve a series of temperature values that can be fed  to a chart in the Node Red dashboard.  Alternatively, if I am storing the data incorrectly, how should the messages feeding the data to influxdb be formatted? Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the actual text and then format it with the options in the tool bar(code formatting is best for this sort of thing). Images can be hard to read and impossible for people who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I had to convert the comma-separated values generated by my sensor into an "object" using the CSV node in Node Red ... then all the fields fell into place!